# onclick handler on <a> tags, find out which tag was clicked

Tags: javascript, html, dojo, dom-events

I have 5 anchor tags on my page. Now when one of these tags gets clicked I want to call a JavaScript function, in this function I need to find out which of the anchors was clicked.

How can this be handled?
I want to do it in pure JavaScript or with dojo.

Answer (score 3):

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for(var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    anchors[i].onclick = function() {
        alert(this.id);
        doStuff(id);
        return false;   
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/FVWqT/1/

Note, if you have more than five anchors, and want to target only specific ones, you might want to filter by class, for example:

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for(var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    if(anchors[i].className == "something") {
        anchors[i].onclick = function() {
            alert(this.id);
            doStuff(id);
            return false;   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you better have this code in the onload event of the document, so that all anchor tags will be there for sure. also correcting minor typo, it should be: if(anchors[i].className == "something") { :-)

Comment: cheers, my pleasure.. by the way won't it be more efficient to use the same function?

Comment: can i add the event handler in propery if ancor as onclick="testfunction"?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of defining an onclick handler for each link in page, for a better performance you could use event delegation on links container (this technique fits perfectly on your task), e.g.

```
(function() {
   var divcnt = document.getElementById('linkcnt');
    divcnt.onclick = function(evt) {

        var event = (evt || window.event),
            target = (event.target || event.srcElement);

        if (evt.target.tagName === 'A') {
           // event.target is DOM reference to link you clicked
           // evt.target.id  is the ID;
           alert(evt.target.id);

           //callmyfunction(event.target) // Call a function with DOM reference
        }
    }
})();
```

See a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/fcalderan/MSvvh/

Comment: event delegation works in all current browser because of event bubbling. You're capturing click when event arrives to the container.

Answer (score 1):

No complex constructs needed, try it your self in the address bar:

```
javascript:(
  function () {
    for (var i=0; i<document.links.length; i++)
      document.links[i].onclick = function () {
        return confirm(this.href+'\nORLY?')
      };
  }
)();
```